# Effects of Current Fluctuations on Charging

Tags: battery, charging

iPhones, iPad, etc, all have their optimal specifications for charging. A power source that does not meet those specification results in a slow charge. However, what happens when the specifications (volt/amps) increased & decrease (fluctuate)? Will the power fluctuations cause damage to the battery? Assuming there is a voltage regulator to keep it from going too high, will this still cause damage?

Comment: These kinds of issues usually are tested by the manufacturer. Theoretically it shouldn't be a problem (no guarantee, I've never tried). Your other option is to directly buy solar cells and charge a battery that outputs electricity at a suitable voltage.

Comment: Are you using the original apple charger? What does you solar panel setup look like, is it a off the shelf system or something you designed? Need more info.

Comment: @user3623501 Found a general model that may resemble the final array I settle on.

Comment: Rephrased the question to be less specific to myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting directly the solar panel to your iPhone will have negative influence on your battery.

Solar system that are design to charge the phone/GPS/what so ever, use a second battery as buffer. Do you use a system that has not one.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question to show what solar array I might buy. It is designed for charging and has some protection. Will it still have a negative influence?

Comment: The only worry you should have is the fluctuating power. This will not happen if buffer battery charges the iPhone

Answer (score 0):

I was recently told by my landlords electrician that the voltage in my flat fluctuates quite badly, and that it can contribute to some devices having shorter lifespans.

But where I notice it most is in charging my phone, on a full charge at home my phone will last around 10 hours with a couple of hours of screen on time.

When I charge the same phone at my parents house, with similar power usage, wi-fi turned on, same apps syncing ect. It will last nearly 24 hours with 5-6 hours of screen on time.

This is all using the same charging brick and lead. The only solution the electrician told me about, was some sort of regulator that could be fitted to normalize the voltages. He said that it would cost a couple of hundred £'s :(

Comment: I think this is unlikely.  The AC voltage fluctuation could possibly damage the charger eventually, but as long as you are using a high quality charger, like the Apple-branded one, the DC output will be quite stable at 5V.  You can buy a cheap device to measure this if you are curious.  Google "USB charge doctor".